# why aspect ratio is not working with images

Tags: css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]so am having a problem with setting an aspect ratio of on all my image for some reason it doesn't work properly or at all, I did not set a set width or fixed height on any of the images. I only set a width of 100% was set so that it did not overflow and take up the entire page k and all of the are svg images.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
   <section class="bg-lightcareml container">
        <div class="container-section">
            <h2 class="prod-items">Our Products</h2>
            <div class="card-items">



                <div class="card">

                    <img src="svg images/Men hooded shirt 1.svg" class="card-img" alt="">

                    <div class="card-text">
                        <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum perferendis iure asperiores
                            dicta quis vel fugiat, soluta nam laboriosam.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="card">

                    <img src="svg images/Men hooded shirt 1.svg" class="card-img" alt="">
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint tempore doloremque vero
                            placeat officiis eaque nisi velit rerum dolorums.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <img src="svg images/Men hooded shirt 1.svg" class="card-img" alt="">

                    <div class="card-text">
                        <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis nulla numquam in
                            provident deserunt! Cumque excepturi delectus
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

      
    </body>

    </html>

     
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        html {
            font-size: 62.2%;
            font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        
        }
        
        
        body {
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 1.3175rem;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }
        
        .bg-lightblue {
            background-color: var(--clr-pr-300);
            height: 12vh;
        
        
        
        }
        
        .container {
            margin-inline: auto;
            width: min(95%, 210rem);
        
        }
        
        
        
        .bg-lightcareml {
            background-color: var(--clr-pr-400);
        
        }
        
        .container-section {
            margin-top: 3rem;
            min-height: 820px;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 4rem;
            padding: 0.6rem;
        }
        
        .container-section>.prod-items {
        
            text-align: center;
            font-size: x-large;
            font-family: var(--ff-pr);
        
        }
        
        .prod-items {
            padding: 1.8rem 0 0 0;
            color: var(--clr-pr-200);
        }
        
        
        .card-items {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-top: 1rem;
        
        
        
            gap: 2.5rem;
        
        }
        
        
        .card {
            display: flex;
        
        
            flex: 0 0 250px;
        
        
            flex-direction: column;
        
        
        
        }
        
        .card .card-text {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        
        
        
        
        
        }
        
        .card-text {
            background: var(--clr-ctrl-100);
            padding: 1.2rem;
            margin-top: -6px;
        
        }
        
        @media (max-width:35rem) {
            .container-section {
                padding: 2rem;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
        
                flex-shrink: 0;
            }
        
            .card-items {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                margin-top: 1rem;
                max-width: 300px;
        
            }
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        h2,
        p {
            line-height: 1.4;
            font-size: 1.666rem;
            font-weight: 500;
        
        }
        
        h2 {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.76rem;
        }
        
        .card-items h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        
        .card-items p {
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 930px
        }
        
        
        .card-img img {
            aspect-ratio: 2 / 3;
        
            width: 100%;
        
        }
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfIgR.jpg
```

Comment: Click the button with brackets `<>` and enter code within those boxes. Also, before you save it, please click the tidy button.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle or share the svg's by any link

Comment: ok but ow do i do that

Comment: Removing `alt` on img might help you. It is weird but it works